# Python sorting a list of dictionaries by the value of a key

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Sorry my first post has to be a question. 
I did some searching and couldn't find the way to sort a list of dictionaries based on one key.

Assume I have this list of dictionaries

```
[0]{Number:123, Name:Bill, Age:32, Sex:Male}
[1]{Number:93, Name:Billy, Age:23, Sex:Male}
[2]{Number:113, Name:Billie, Age:32, Sex:Female}
[3]{Number:8, Name:Wills, Age:3, Sex: Male}
[4]{Number:8, Name:Wills, Age:4, Sex: Male}
[5]{Number:8, Name:Wills, Age:5, Sex: Male}
[6]{Number:8, Name:Wills, Age:6, Sex: Male}
```

I'd like to sort or iterate over this list on Number:value and then by Age:value so that the new list is like this

```
[0]{Number:8, Name:Wills, Age:3, Sex: Male}
[1]{Number:8, Name:Wills, Age:4, Sex: Male}
[2]{Number:8, Name:Wills, Age:5, Sex: Male}
[3]{Number:8, Name:Wills, Age:6, Sex: Male}
[4]{Number:93, Name:Billy, Age:23, Sex:Male}
[5]{Number:113, Name:Billie, Age:32, Sex:Female}
[6]{Number:123, Name:Bill, Age:32, Sex:Male}
```

So far I've only been able to sort a key inside the list, which sorted the dict entry within the list, and kept the list indexes the same.  Which wasn't what I wanted.

```
sorted_data_list = sorted(data_list, key = lambda x: x['Number'])
```

edit: made list contiguous.

Comment: Sorry I had been del from a list but not this one.  It is contiguous.

Comment: it's 9400 items long with 36 elements in each dict lol!

Comment: Your question's been answered, but for next time you can just include a small portion of the real data - what you've posted doesn't make sense as Python, so it's hard to figure out what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the key to lambda x: (x['Number'], x['Age'])

This creates a tuple, and tuples are sorted by first element, then second element.

Comment: sorted_data_list = sorted(data_list, key = lambda[x]: (x['Number'], x['Age'])) gives a syntax error on the [x] (debugger says formal parameter name expected)

Comment: Should be ```lambda x```, not ```lambda [x]```

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. Should be lambda x (without the []) instead

Comment: Thanks gentlemen.  Marking as answer with sorted_data_list = sorted(data_list, key = lambda x: (x['Number'], x['Age']))

Comment: @Joylove no need to assume folks are gentlemen.